# POSIX thread Programming in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, posix

I am trying to add two matrices using pthreads.Just a beginners program,but I am unable to initialize the matrix using threads.my code snippet is as follows:

```
#include "test.h"

CvMat * matA;       /* first matrix */
CvMat * matB;       /* second matrix */
CvMat * matRes;     /* result matrix */

int size_x_a; /* this variable will be used for the first  dimension */
int size_y_a; /* this variable will be used for the second dimension */

int size_x_b,size_y_b;
int size_x_res;
int size_y_res;

int main()
{
/* assigining the values of sizes */
size_x_a = 200;
size_y_a = 200;
size_x_b = 200;
size_y_b = 200;

/* resultant matrix dimensions */
size_x_res = size_x_a;
size_y_res = size_y_b;

matA = cvCreateMat(size_x_a,size_y_a,CV_32SC1);
matB = cvCreateMat(size_x_b,size_y_b,CV_32SC1);
matRes = cvCreateMat(size_x_res,size_y_res,CV_32SC1);

pthread_t thread1;
pthread_t thread2;

int res1;
int res2;
 /*******************************************************************************/ 

    /*Creating a thread*/
res1 = pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,initializeA,(void*)matA);
if(res1!=0)
{
    perror("thread creation of thread1 failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for(int i =0;i<size_x_a;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;j<size_y_a;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",cvmGet(matA,i,j));
    }
}
    /*Creating a thread*/
res2 = pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,initializeB,(void*)matB);

if(res2!=0)
{
    perror("thread creation of thread2 failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
return 0;
 }

void * initializeA(void * arg)
{
CvMat * matA  = (CvMat*)arg;
//matA = (CvMat*)malloc(size_x_a * sizeof(CvMat *));

/*initialiazing random values*/
for (int i = 0; i < size_x_a; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size_y_a; j++) 
    {
        cvmSet(matA,i,j,size_y_a + j); 
    }
}
return 0;
}

void * initializeB(void * arg)
{
CvMat* matB  = (CvMat*)arg;
//matB = (CvMat*)malloc(size_x_b * sizeof(CvMat *));

/*initialiazing random values*/
for (int i = 0; i < size_x_b; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size_y_b; j++) 
    {
      cvmSet(matB,i,j,size_y_b + j); 
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I have first created two threads to initialize the CvMat matrix.CvMat matrix is of opencv.
after initializing and calling pthread_create I am trying to access the data of CvMat but it is crashing,means it is not initialized.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Comment: if you test if `matA` is `NULL` before the line `Ares1 = pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,initializeA,(void*)matA);` what is the result?

Comment: This is likely to be an excercise where you have to use `pthreads`, but please remember that in modern C++ one should use `<thread>` and `<mutex>`. It is supported by all the major compilers in their latest version (gcc 4.6+, clang 3.0+, MSVC 2010+).

Comment: @Yannick Blondeau : No its not NULL it has some address.

Comment: @J.N. : is it supported on android..??

Comment: @J.N.: `<thread>` and `<mutex>` are not supported in MSVC 2010 but are (I'm not sure how completely) in MSVC 2012.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: oops my bad, thanks ! Though, I am sure it is supported completely in MSVC 2012 (MS explicitely stated that the full standard library was implemented).

Comment: @user1393349: no idea, sorry, it depends on your toolset I guess ... if it's using a recent GCC then probably, if not, you're out of luck... You may be able to force it by linking statically to the standard library but that won't be super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have to wait until the initialization is finished before use.

```
pthread_create(&thr1, ..., (void *)matA);
pthread_create(&thr2, ..., (void *)matB);

pthread_join(thr1, &result1);
pthread_join(thr2, &result2);

for (...) { ... cvmGet(matA,i,j); ... }
```

As it stands you're trying to access the matrix during its initialization.